# Insert Array Into Database using Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to insert candidate language information into db and only for authenticated user. Candidate can add more languages. All info insert for the authenticated  user.Authenticated Candidate can also

Here is my view code:

```
  <form action="{{url('/candidate/addLanguage')}}" method="post">
      @csrf    
                         
    
       <!-- Education -->
       <div class="form with-line">
          <h5>Language  Proficiency</h5>
              <div class="form-inside">
                <!-- Add Education -->
            <div class="form boxed box-to-clone education-box">
<a href="#" class="close-form remove-box button"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
    
 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="inputEmail4"> Language</label>
     <input type="text" name="txt_language[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Language">
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputPassword4">Reading</label>
       <select name="txt_reading[]" id="" class="form-control">
       <option value="#" selected>Choose..</option>
      <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
    </select>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label for="inputEmail4"> Writing</label>
          <select name="txt_writing[]" id="" class="form-control">
           <option value="#" selected>Choose..</option>
           <option value="High">High</option>
           <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
           <option value="Low">Low</option>
         </select>
   </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="inputPassword4">Speaking</label>
   <select name="txt_speaking[]" id="" class="form-control">
       <option value="#" selected>Choose..</option>
       <option value="High">High</option>
       <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
    
<a href="#" class="button gray add-education add-box"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Language</a>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

My Controller :

```
 public function addLanguage(Request $request){
    
        $candidateID =  Auth::guard('candidate')->user()->id;
        if (count($request->txt_language) > 0){
    
            foreach ($request->txt_language as $language => $l){
                   $data = array(
                    'candidate_id' =>  $candidateID,
                    'language' =>  $request->txt_language[$language],
                    'reading' =>  $request->txt_reading[$language],
                    'writing' =>  $request->txt_writing[$language],
                    'speaking' =>  $request->txt_speaking[$language],
                
                ) ;
                     Language::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/candidate/referencesForm')->with('success','Language Information Save Successfully..');
    }
```

I get this error :

```
 Attempt to assign property 'candidate_id' of non-object
```

Where I missing anything? How can I solve this error? Please Help

its  "dd($request->all()); " output:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "pcKuRe8xI8WzRYQefwY7GMw1Zo6vighrZ6k7PUNi"
  "txt_language" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "English"
    1 => "Bangla"
    2 => null
  ]
  "txt_reading" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Medium"
    1 => "Medium"
    2 => "High"
  ]
  "txt_writing" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "High"
    1 => "Low"
    2 => "High"
  ]
  "txt_speaking" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "High"
    1 => "High"
    2 => "High"
  ]
]
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $('.box-to-clone').show();
    $('.add-box').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newElem = $(this).parent().find('.box-to-clone:first').clone();
        newElem.find('input').val('');
        newElem.prependTo($(this).parent()).show();
        var height = $(this).prev('.box-to-clone').outerHeight(true);
        $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top-height}, 600);
    });
    $('body').on('click','.remove-box', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: We find the question bit confusing.. could you please add more details on what you were trying and your expectation

Comment: I have a "language" form for authenticated candidate. I want to insert data into DB using the form to the specific candidate.Candidate can add more languages and all insert that specific candidate. but  I get this error in this line "$language->candidate_id =>  $candidateID,"

Comment: try $data = Language::create([ $language->candidate_id =>  $candidateID, ..... ]); You are missing arrow

Comment: Now "Trying to get property 'candidate_id' of non-object" getting this error.

Comment: my bad, $data = Language::create([ 'candidate_id' => $candidateID, ..... ]);

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'candidate_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `languages` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-09-13 07:09:09, 2020-09-13 07:09:09))

Comment: The error means that either the $candidateID is empty or you have missed to add the keys to the fillable in model.. Please check if you are getting value for this. use print_r($candidateID). If this has value check if the 'candidate_id' value is added to fillable propery in Language Model

Comment: print_r($candidateID) is working it shows id.

Comment: kindly edit the question and  paste the output of your request - dd($request->all()); .

Comment: I updated, sir.

Comment: we were doing it wrong way whole time.. we need to loop each one(such as txt_language , txt_reading,...)  .. Add foreach for each element. OR create a new question asking on how to save the above array list to database.. It's bit advanced to me

Comment: Were the records being saved when you tried the foreach ($request->txt_language as $language => $l){
    $data = new  Language;
    $data->candidate_id => $candidateID,             
    $data->save();
}

Remove everything else inside the the for loop

Comment: Sir its worked but only 1 row. Suppose "0" indexed saved but "1" index missing.What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below format,

```
foreach ($request->txt_language as $language => $l){
    $data = new  Language;
    $data->candidate_id => $candidateID,
    $data->language =>  $request->txt_language[$language],
    $data->reading =>  $request->txt_reading[$language],
    $data->writing =>  $request->txt_writing[$language],
    $data->speaking =>  $request->txt_speaking[$language],                 
    $data->save();
}
```

Hope this would fix your issue. Let me know if you face further issue.

Comment: Now "Trying to get property 'candidate_id' of non-object" getting this error.

Comment: yes its work but only for one row. I want to add  multiply row for for 1 candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  public function addLanguage(Request $request){

    $candidateID =  Auth::guard('candidate')->user()->id;
   if(!empty($candidateID)){
    if (count($request->txt_language) > 0){
        foreach ($request->txt_language as $language => $l){
                 Language::create([
                 'candidate_id' =>  $candidateID,
                'language' =>  $l,
                'reading' =>  $request->txt_reading[$language],
                'writing' =>  $request->txt_writing[$language],
                'speaking' =>  $request->txt_speaking[$language],
           ]);
        }
       }
      return redirect('/candidate/referencesForm')->with('success','Language Information Save Successfully..');
    }
     abort(404);
}
```

Comment: Data saved into DB but if I input 2 row its get 1 row.  print_r( $data) show just 1 data. Other data missing.